# How do I best handle coroutine concurrency?

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a project with a recyclerview list (which data resides on Room db) and a google map. On the googlemap, there is drawn different types of Markers collected from the Room db and actions done in the list is drawn on the map (i.e. changing Marker.visibility, color, etc and so on) all of this works quite well, until...

An user does an action in the list (updating the room db), the livedata observes and starts the processes (which may be timeconsuming), which I solved by calling `lifeCycleScope.launchWhenStarted` and in there uses a `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` on the timeconsuming part, porting each change to the googleMap using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` in there again. This works quite well.

Since the `withContext(Dispathcers.Default)` continues the work, the actual observer runs to the end, and new livedata observables may trigger.

The second observable triggering may then start before the coroutine part is finished, and I may run into concurrency errors. Is there a "sane" way to "halt" the processing of the second attempt (or all subsequent attempts) inside the `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` (somekind of "waitFor" condition) and let them start when the ongoing process is finished ?

I.E. code:

```
myLiveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner){myData->
  
  lifeCycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
    //do some context main work
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
      //Do some heavy work pt 1
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {/*Update views*/}
      //Do some heavy work pt 2
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {/*Update views2*/} 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: did you consider the use of a mutex from the coroutines core library?  https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/

Comment: @PietroScarampella do you have any good examples on how the Mutex handle subsequent calls to this observer, can they queue up gracefully ?

Comment: ...by that I mean: when two or more subsequent attempts, who of them will react when mutex is unlocked, just one, or both, or do they queue somehow.

Comment: If you do not care about the order of the subsequent calls, a mutex is a good choice since it will be locked by the first task that asks for it. But if the order matters to you then use an `actor`, the actor is atomic and the message that you sent to it are executed sequentially: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#actors

Comment: Instead of a LiveData you could use a Flow along with the `collectLatest` operator which cancels an ongoing operation as soon as a new value arrives.

Comment: @PietroScarampella at the moment the order of the calls may matter, if they turn/on off markers subsequently I can get in a situation where my state button is off and the marker is on... so `actor` may be the solution in a short hand. In broader perspective Flow is preferable, but at the moment I have less experience with Flow (something new to learn/should have learned) and how it will affect my app design. If you  have time, please suggest as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order matters to you, I suggest the use of an `actor` to handling sequential computation as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#actors)